# Javascript Color Guessing Game for my course work

Tags: javascript

I need help with my coding. I am new to this and just starting out on this great journey. When I start the game, the dialog box comes up for me to answer but when I submit a color, it just goes away. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Color Guessing Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Color Guessing Game</h1>
    <button type="button" onclick ="runGame()">Start Game</button>
    <script>
        const COLORS_ARRAY = ['blue', 'cyan','gold','gray','green','magenta','orange','red','white','yellow.']
        function runGame(){
        let guess = ' ';
        let correct = false;
        let numTries = 0;
        const targetIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * COLORS_ARRAY.length);
        const target = COLORS_ARRAY[targetIndex];
        console.log(target)
           
        
            do{
            guess = prompt('I am thinking of one of these colors:\n\n' + COLORS_ARRAY +'What color am I thinking of?\n');
            numTries += 1;
            if(guess === null){
            alert('Have a great day!');
            }
            return false;
            correct = checkGuess (guess, target);
            } while(!correct);
             alert("Congrats! You got it"+ target + " \n\nIt took you" + numtries + "tries to guess correctly"); 
             document.body.style.background = guess;
        }     
            function checkGuess(guess,target){
            let correct = false;
            console.log (guess);
            if (!COLORS_ARRAY.includes(guess)){
                alert('You have not entered a color from the list\n\nPlease choose a color from the before mentioned list.');
            }else if (guess > target) {
                alert('Your choice is alphabetically higher than the color.');
            }else if (guess < target) {
                alert('Your choice is alphabetically lower than the color.');
            }else {
            correct= true;
            }
            return correct;
            }
           
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you return false before `checkGuess`?

Comment: Why do you make `guess`, `target` parameters to `checkGuess()` function when you declared them as variables in first ?

Comment: Correct, it was a mistake....I removed the false and moved it under the brace.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. For the best responses, try and only post the part of the code that you are having trouble with. In this case the important parts are the prompt call and the if(guess === null). Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

I think firstly you need to get into the habit of using namespace. The global javascript environment has a lot of things in there, which could cause conflicts (and data mutations).

Example:

```
const g = {}
g.colorArray = ["Blue","Red","Green"]
g.getColor = function() {// gets the color}
g.setColor = function() {// sets the color}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are querying if `guess === null` using strict equality but prompt returns a string. For example, if the user types nothing the value of guess will be `''`.

You can test for nullish and no response strings using `guess == null` which will return true if the guess is undefined, null or `""`.

However most of the time you would also be testing for strings that contain nothing but spaces. In this guess you can use `guess == null || guess.trim().length === 0`. This will remove spaces from the guess and then check the length. If it is zero, then it will return true.

Some reading on strict equality vs regualar equality

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality